# How do you check for user input in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

Not text. Buttons. I want to program on Unity and can't figure out how to read inputs because "user input" and "keyboard input" results on Google are just how to use Console.WriteLine() and Console.ReadLine().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like move your player pressing w or something like that you could do this.

Input.GetKey("w");

That returns a bool that you can check on the update with an if statement, if the key is pressed, it would be true, so you can write what you want to do inside.
Try that.